# Magmi Configurable Products upload causing errors

Tags: magento, magmi, configurable-product

I'm getting the following errors in Magmi after trying to import a CSV file with Magmi:

> ```
> error 1:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null - INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (?,?,?)
> error 2:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null - ERROR ON RECORD #10
> warning:Skus imported KO:1/10
> ```

I'm at my wit's end and have googled to the end of the earth for a solution, but haven't been able to find one.  What am I doing wrong?  I will post my upload sheet below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjkeS.png

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: are your config_color & config_size attributes :
 - global scope
 - dropdown
 - use for configurable 
This is mandatory for using them in configurable_attributes column.

Comment: One thing in your file that's different to mine is that I have "/" as delimiters for my configurable_attributes. I would suggest that you manually create the products and export them using the standard Magento export. That will then give you the right column headers and you can then amend your csv file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, everyone.  As per dweeves' comment, and from the help of Matt at UnderstandingE, I went to check first that my config_colour and config_size were the correct column headers and configurable attributes that I wanted, and indeed after changing them to just "color" and "size," the results came out favorable.  Simple fix to a simple issue, I guess.  Thanks for all the help.